# How can I make a parent element overlap child elements when using absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css

In this example, the `z-index` properties I've just set do not work because parent/child elements have the same z-indexes. I would like to know if there is - even this not being a good practice - any way to make a parent overlap its child.

```
.parent {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1000px;
  width: 500px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;   
  width: 70px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/caiocavalcante063/pen/BaWmxvy)

I am basically looking for a way to make the black element overlap the red one, without changing any HTML structure, using only CSS.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This feels like an XY problem: if you really want the parent to completely overlay the child, why not switch their relationship around? It's trivial to ensure the child completely overlays the parent.

Comment: Please fix up the demo snippet I added so it shows your problem rather than giving us images. And yes, there's probably a better way. Consider expanding your question to ask about the actual problem instead of your proposed solution.

Comment: Asking for a solution that you expect to be a bad practice doesn't sound like a good idea. As others have mentioned, your question should contain your actual problem, not just asking how to implement what you think the solution should be.